# How to inform Ubuntu 12.04 apt-get about older installed version of php

Tags: php, ubuntu, apt-get

Recently installed php5.3.22 on Ubuntu 12.04 from an excellent install script provided by  git://github.com/vladgh/VladGh.com-LEMP.git. This works perfectly.

The issue I have is that I now want to also install phpunit.
When i try apt-get install phpunit - It wants to also include a bunch of dependencies such as php5-common, etc. (I suspect apt-get does not already know that I have php5.3.22 installed and wants to install php5.4.x - since it is the distro release version.)

I do not want to conflict/overwrite my (already tuned) php5.3.22 install.

I thought about using a php phar file to run php unit. but first want to know if anyone knows simple step by step instructions to inform apt-get about the existing php5.3.22 install so that I can use apt-get in the future to configure php for upgrades, add modules, etc.

There are many questions about installing older versions of software on Ubuntu, but I am looking specifically to inform the package management system about which is the installed current version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use equivs to inform the package management system that you've installed software through other means. See, e.g., http://blog.andrewbeacock.com/2005/09/creating-dummy-debian-package-for.html - credit: https://serverfault.com/users/48857/mark-wagner and andrew beacock

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using composer in your PHP project to manage/install phpunit.

Just add the following to your composer.json file

```
"require-dev": {
    "phpunit/PHPUnit": "3.7.*"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Lee, but what i am really after is a way to tell apt-get about the current version of php that already exists on my system so that i can use apt-get to do upgrades. your suggestions is a good alternative to get the project working with the required dependencies. but I think that can also be accomplished with phar right?

Comment: perhaps this is a serverfault question?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/users/48857/mark-wagner